# How to replace "," with ", "?

Tags: php, regex, string

I want to replace "Some Sentence,Some Sentence" in a string with "Some Sentence,[Space]Some Sentence".

I tried `str_replace(",", ", ",$str)`, but the problem is that this replace both "," and ",[Space]" creating ",[Space]" and ",[Space][Space]". Is there a way to replace only the comma that comes exactly between two Sentences?

I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Look into regular expressions.

Comment: Tag the question with regexp in order to someone with experience in regular expressions to help you.

Comment: see this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/kD5kF5/1)

Comment: What is delimiter between your sentences? Comma? And what if sentence have comma inside, too?

Comment: To add space where a word is bordering, use a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html): `$str = preg_replace('/,\b/', ", ", $str);` If you have comma numbers such as `1,1` in your text: [Look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for an alpha `/,(?=[a-z])/i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$string = 'Some Sentence,Some Sentence don\'t touch, this one but,thisone do, also';
echo preg_replace('~,([^\s])~', ', $1', $string);
```

That says find a comma `,` without a whitespace as the next character `[^\s]`. The `[]` is a character class listing characters and the `^` makes it a negative search. The `~`s are delimiters telling where the regex starts and ends.

Update: The `()` captures the non-whitespace character and returns it with the `,` and space.

The `\s` is any white space character (tab, newline, space). If you only want space change that to `\h` which is a horizontal space.

Regex101 demo: https://regex101.com/r/eU1iR1/2

Update:

An alternative approach:

```
$string = 'Some Sentence,Some Sentence don\'t touch, this one but,thisone do, also';
    echo preg_replace('~,\s(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|,~', ', ', $string);
```

which says if it finds a comma with whitespace first skip it otherwise add the comma with a whitespace. Here's an article on that approach, http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html.

Demo:https://regex101.com/r/eG8jS8/1

Comment: When I applied this to `Experimental Physics,Gravitational Physics,Dark Matter,Dark Energy` I got `Experimental Physics, ravitational Physics, ark Matter, ark Energy` Why is this?

Comment: Ah, it still found the non-whitespace character so that needs to be captured. Updated answer.

Comment: Your second solution is overkill for this simple problem. Also, the feature is not available in most languages, so it's best to try writing regex without them first.

Answer (score 1):

If the delimiter is consistent, you could also leverage straight string operations:

```
$foo = "Something,Something";
$bar = implode(", ", explode(",", $foo));
```

`explode` creates an array, using the delimiter as a token. `implode` concatenates it back using the new delimiter.

*note: this would **not** take into account scenarios where spaces (and other characters) are significant.  But is a simple alternative.*

Comment: Actually, i don't understand what is delimiter in this case at all... if it is just one comma - OP simple str_replace should work,too. Obviously, there are some white space chars between...

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to do it like this:

```
$str = str_replace(", ", ",", $str);
$str = str_replace(",", ", ",$str);
```

While regex solution is more powerful (it works on unlimited spaces), this one is perhaps more newbie friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use a negative look-ahead to check that the character following a `,` is not a whitespace character before replacing it with `,` :

```
$str = "begin,space, no sp,   not space,space,,~~~,@@##$,end";
$str = preg_replace('/,(?!\s)/', ", ", $str);
```

Output: `begin, space, no sp,   not space, space, , ~~~, @@##$, end`

[**Demo on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/gX0uB0/1)